# Writing URL variables in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on a project using CodeIgniter, though I still a bit new on this PHP language framework.
I need to create multiple variables URL in CodeIgniter like:

```
index.php?page=10&filter=voted
```

How do you write it in CI? I know if it's only one variable then it should be

```
index.php/page/10
```

If the URL contains two or more variables, should it be like this or not? And how do you retrieve them since it uses URI Segment?

```
index.php/page/10/filter/voted
```

Much thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get data using segment.

```
 $this->uri->segment(1);
 $this->uri->segment(2);
 $this->uri->segment(3);
```

or 
get all segment in array

```
$segment = $this->uri->segment_array();
print_r($segment);
```

Comment: Thanks. How do you write the URL in Codeigniter? I need to put the url in an anchor link.

Comment: <a herf="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/page/<?php $yourvariable ?>/<?php $yourvariable ?>/<?php $yourvariable ?>"

Comment: Thanks. I think I know what to do know.